# Xpages delay time when composing a new document

Tags: xpages

```
<xp:button value="  Add" id="button1">

    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:openPage name="/doc.xsp" target="newDocument"></xp:openPage>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

But, I have to wait up to 8 seconds - 10 seconds, for the structure document to appear. Also, in its structure there are displayed maximum 10-15 fields binded to datasource. There are as well some partial refreshes but everything goes OK, the delay time is only when I access the above button.

Is this a server issue? What can causes the above delay via the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the setting "Do not validate or update data" to the button. That will prevent any of the page lifecycle occurring for the current page for that button. You're redirecting to a new page and running no other code, so there's no need to update the current page.

If it's still taking a long time, it's a problem on the page you're going to.

Comment: I've added the setting, but no changes seen. Interesting is the fact that I use the same method/code for other applications where the doc. structure is more complex than this one, and the delay/waiting time is shorter.

Comment: Do you get the same performance hit on every other XPage on that server? If not, it's nothing to do with the server. The subsequent question is do you get the same performance when going directly to the page via a url, e.g. /doc.xsp?action=createDocument ? From what you've said so far, I would expect that you do. In which case there is a performance issue somewhere on that XPage, which you will need to troubleshoot to identify the cause

Comment: Only when I access the respective xpage @ doc.xsp?action=newDocument . I tried also just opening the xpage: doc.xsp, but same situation. Sincerely, after adding the "Do not validate or update data", the waiting time is lower, but I still have to wait some seconds. I have also other applications where I'm using page.xsp?action=newDocument, with more complex structure ( more fields ) but the page loading is a lot faster.

Comment: I added refreshMode="norefresh" to my button which opens the xpage, and now it is opened OK. But, could I have some issues removing the refreshMode="complete"?

Comment: You shouldn't. The only behaviour you're losing by not running a refresh is passing any updates the user has made to the current page to the server-side map of the page. But that would only be of relevance if you were also saving a document or navigating to a new page in a view, and *then* opening the page. None of that is occurring.

Comment: For my case, it seemed that modifying the above attribute was the problem. Now, the xpage is opened fine.